# Image not assigning in Unity3d

Tags: image, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a puzzle game project in Unity3D and when I'm trying to assign a new image in script in the inspector view, it is still reading the old image by default. But the the field now has updated to new image name, and if I delete the old image, it is not showing up any image at all, just a gray color object.

What's wrong?

This is the image of the inspector view

[image]

Comment: how you are trying to assign new image in script?

Comment: @SheheryarAamir Please check the image.. I'm trying to click and select a new image. The image name is successfully updated but unity is still using old image.

Answer (score 0):

The gray color means there is no image defined for that object. Try to make sure you have the reference to the image setup. Also try to reopen the scene to see the reflected changes.

Comment: I've tried reopening many times.. Even restarted the PC. Still it doesnt go away. :(

Comment: oh you are using a script.. maybe you are setting the image inside your script - Demo. If u set the image in the code, the image changing in the inspector will not help. I suggest you remove any assigning done to your images in the script first and then try updating in the inspector.

Comment: I have not set the image in the code at all. That is the reason I'm using the inspector view. I don't understand why sometimes Unity behaves like a retard. I wasted 6 hours straight on this but still didn't found any solution till now. :(

Comment: have u tried dragging the image onto the plane directly in the scene like [here](http://www.gunhansancar.com/blog/how-to-display-image-on-a-plane-in-unity-3d/)

Comment: The image that you tried to assign is assigned to a script. Try assigning to the object(on which the image needs to be rendered) directly if you are not using the script to load images.

Comment: Also try to paste the Demo script details.